# Python error : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python

I wanna make word count and list how many times word counted. But

---

```
 f = open("Les.Miserable.txt", 'r')

 words = f.read().split()
 words.sort()
 wordCount = ()

 for i in range(len(words)):
     words[i] = words[i].replace(".", ""), (",", ""), ("/", ""), ("?", ""), ("!", "")
     words[i] = words[i].upper()
     if words[i] not in wordCount:
         wordCount[words[i]] = 1 
     else:
         wordCount[words[i]] += 1
```

i can see error message 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper' in

```
words[i] = words[i].upper()
```

here

and also error message 'tuple' object does not support item assignment in

wordCountint[words[i]] = 1

Please let me know know what is the problem

Comment: you can add print before statement to find out type of object.

Comment: i find out what type it is by print(type(words[i])) = class str , but it doesn't work

Comment: Why are making `wordCount` a tuple not a list?

Comment: find out what type is `words` not `words[i]`

Comment: type(words) is list type. I still confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line:

```
words[i] = words[i].replace(".", ""), (",", ""), ("/", ""), ("?", ""), ("!", "")
```

you assign tuple into `words[i]`.
i guess you want to replace several character and that you mean to do this:

```
words[i] = words[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "")
```

several values with comma between them are tuple.
`1,5,6` is the same as `(1,5,6)`
so
 `words[i].replace(".", ""), (",", ""), ("/", ""), ("?", ""), ("!", "")`
is the same as
 `(words[i].replace(".", ""), (",", ""), ("/", ""), ("?", ""), ("!", ""))`

in addition, you can't assign into tuple, therefore. the line

```
wordCount[words[i]] = 1
```

can throw an exception, you need to change `wordCountint` to a dict (when you create it):

```
wordCount = {}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have changed it but it still error on here  wordCount[words[i]] = 1
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I replaced like this    words[i] = words[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "") but there is another error on if words[i] not in wordCount:
        wordCount[words[i]] = 1  and error says 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: change `wordCount = ()` to `wordCount = []` (you can't assign into tuple, however you can into list)

Comment: i changed to [] and error says : list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: oops, you are right, I meant dictionary. change to `{}`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Now it works without any error. Can I ask how can I list it from word that most appeared from wordCount

Comment: wordCount is like this : {'INTEREST,': 1, 'COMMAND': 1, "'WHY": 8, 'NEITHER': 7, 'SHOES': 1, 'ADVANCE': 1, 'TIME,': 16, 'QUICKLY': 14, ..........}

Comment: I don't understand the question. if this answer helped you, please accept it, and ask the new question in a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you print the value of `words[i]` after your attempted character replacements you will see that it is set to a `tuple`, e.g.

```
('word', (',', ''), ('/', ''), ('?', ''), ('!', ''))
```

So the line that tries to remove unwanted punctuation actually creates a tuple because that's what the comma separated items are, i.e.

```
words[i].replace(".", ""), (",", ""), ("/", ""), ("?", ""), ("!", "")
```

is actually a tuple consisting of `words[i].replace(".", "")` followed by `(",", "")`, etc.

You might have meant to chain a whole lot of replace operations together, but that would need to look like this:

```
words[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "")
```

But that is pretty ugly, and it's restricted to just a few punctuation symbols. `str.translate()` is better:

```
words[i] = words[i].translate(None, '.,/?!')
```

or, if you want to get rid of all punctuation you can use `string.punctuation`:

```
import string
words[i] = words[i].translate(None, string.punctuation)
```

Or, if you are using Python 3:

```
import string
words[i] = words[i].({ord(c):None for c in string.punctuation})
```

There are other problems in your code, but see if you can correct this first issue first.

Comment: I changed to what you commented but there is another error on wordCount[words[i]] = 1 . Error says 'tuple' object does not support item assignment. could i know what is wrong?  and i questioned wrong like wordCountint[words[i]] = 1 but wordCount[words[i]] = 1 is right

Answer (score 0):

```
words[i] = words[i].replace(".", ""), (",", ""), ("/", ""), ("?", ""), ("!", "")
```

The above code is making `words` a tuple. And you cannot perform operations like `upper()` on the tuple. Hence, the error.
I think, what you want to do is

```
words[i] = words[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "")
```

Also, you have declare `wordCount = ()` as tuple. You won't be able to edit `wordCount` because of this, and this will lead to an error. It should be a dictionary : `wordCount = {}`

The entire program should look like:

```
f = open("Les.Miserable.txt", 'r')

words = f.read().split()
words.sort()
wordCount = {}

for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i] = words[i].replace(".", "").replace(",", "").replace("/", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "")
    words[i] = words[i].upper()
    if words[i] not in wordCount:
        wordCount[words[i]] = 1
    else:
        wordCount[words[i]] += 1
sorted_wordCount = sorted(wordCount.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print sorted_wordCount
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have changed it but it still error on here wordCount[words[i]] = 1 TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What is wordCountint[words[i]]? I think the int is wrongly placed there.

Comment: It would be easy for us to help you, if you publish a small snapshot of `Les.Miserable.txt`

Comment: Les miserable strats like this        Chapter one

 Jean Valjean

 One evening in October 1815, an hour before sunset, a man with a long beard and dusty, torn clothes walked into the town of Digne. He was in his late forties, of medium height, broad-shouldered and strong. A leather cap half-hid his face, which was sunburnt and shining with sweat. His rough yellow shirt was unbuttoned, revealing a hairy chest. On his back was a heavy soldier's bag, and in his hand was a large wooden stick.
it is just simple text file

Comment: You have declared `wordCount = ()` on top, which is a tuple. Hence, the error.

Comment: It should be a dictionary : `wordCount = {}`

Comment: @shruti1810 besides that OP says that error is : "i can see error message 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper' in `words[i] = words[i].upper()` "

Comment: @JUPPIN Thats quite easy, will update the code, please do mark it as correct.

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'